# Removing substrings from a Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, replace

I used the following code

```
remove_words=['Conference Call - Final.rtf','Conference Call - F(2).rtf','Final(2).rtf']
pat= '|'.join(remove_words)
pat
df['title'] = df['conference_name'].str.replace(pat,'')
```

but my result was
[image]
my code successfully replaced
[Conference Call - Final.rtf]
but was not able to replace
[Conference Call - F(2).rtf][Final(2).rtf]
my desired output should replace all the substrings which are passed.

Comment: Could you add your results as text rather than screenshots? See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) on [meta].

Comment: As for the question itself -- unless you're using dataframe functionality (it's not a library I'm familiar with) `str.replace()` isn't regex replace; for that, you want `re.sub()`.

Comment: And if it _is_ a regex call -- `(2)` has its own meaning in a regex; it just matches `2`, not `(2)`. Use `re.escape()` to generate a regex that matches your desired strings.

Comment: ...that is: `pat = '|'.join(re.escape(w) for w in remove_words)`

Answer (score 1):

As `Charles Duffy` mentioned in the comments, parentheses have special meaning in a regular expression (signifies a [capturing group](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups)), and you're using the `str.replace` method with its default argument `regex=True`. The `(2)` in your pattern hence interferes with the regex search and replace, and you would have to escape these symbols to signify that you're using the parentheses literally, instead of as a capturing group.

Let's do:

```
remove_words=['Conference Call - Final.rtf','Conference Call - F(2).rtf','Final(2).rtf']
pat = '|'.join(re.escape(w) for w in remove_words)

df['title'] = df['conference_name'].str.replace(pat, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` module to delete specific  strings such as :

```
re.sub("{Conference Call - Final.rtf}",'',df['conference_name'][0])
```